# Calculating a sub percentage when other weighted sub percentages and the total percentage are known.

Tags: finance, average, percentages

I am working on retirement planning and having a problem working out an equation. I have a good model with all retirement funds and projections including deferred growth annuity equations.
I am trying to figure out the correct growth factor to include for the annuity when there are other income streams involved.

Usually, retirement income comes from at least 3 sources *(i)* a Retirement Account distribution (401k,bonds,etc) treated as an annuity, and Other Income not in the annuity including *(ii)* a Pension that might have a fixed payment and *(iii)* Social Security that gets an annual COL increase.

Examples:
A \$6,000 required total first month's income needs to grow at 4% inflation.
Case 1 -trivial
A single source of income means the withdrawal needs to grow at 4%.
Case 2 -simple
Two sources of income at \$3,000 each. One fixed growing at 0%.
This means the withdrawal from the other needs to grow at 8%.
Case 3 -difficult
Two sources of income. One of \$4,000 growing at 2%.  What is the growth required of the other \$2,000 income stream to give the overall total of 4%?
Case X, -I'm really stuck
Three sources of income. A fixed pension of \$1,200 grows at 0%. A SS payment of \$2,200 grows at 3%. What is the growth required of the other \$2,600 income stream from the annuity to give the overall total 4%?
That unknown growth rate is what I need to calculate to put into the annuity equation.

I know this is a weighted percentages problem.
I know that simple arithmetic does not work with percentages.
I can figure it out for individual cases.
But I am looking for an equation I can put in a spreadsheet to run different scenarios.

Is there a simple equation?
I have not been able to come up with one.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far  If you are not able to include the inflation then omit that case. Help us so that we can help you

Comment: Your question is very long, so I did not make the effort to seriously read everything. I suspect 2 different difficulties : one challenge about monthly data mixed with annualy data, and another challenge, your real challenge. Mixing monthly rates and annual rates in inflation is a 'trap', you will probably have more answers if you simplify, and use same periodicity for all our message.

Comment: I edited it to remove extraneous details but adding examples hasn't shortened it :(
I know how to do effective interest rates for different periods and that isn't my issue.  I have removed any mention of that.

Comment: Is it this simple?
$Inflation* TotalNeededIncome = Rannuity*AnnuityAmount + Rpension*PensionAmount + Rss*SSamount$  
Gives the desired rate for the annuity as:  
$Rannuity =  ( Inflation* TotalNeededIncome - Rpension*PensionAmount - Rss*SSamount )  / AnnuityAmount$